# How to search for objects within a specified radius of an XY coordinate (without gems)?

Tags: ruby, math, hash, geometry, geospatial

**-- BACKGROUND --**

First off, unfortunately as the software I'm working with has an in-built Ruby library, it doesn't allow for the installation of gems. I think Geocoder looked promising, alas...

I have X amount of links and nodes in 2D space and I wish to find the closest link to a given XY coordinate. Essentially looking to create my own method to do this, something like:

```
def manual_search_from_point(x, y, distance_from_point_to_search, collection_of_objects)
...
end
```

where "collection_of_objects" is normally an Array of the object group I am trying to retrieve (links).

Unsure if there is a way to continually radially search out further and further (increasing "distance_from_point_to_search") to find objects without already calculating the distance between objects. With that in mind I thought that gathering all links XY coordinates (endpoints etc.) and finding the distance from that point to the initial XY point may be worthwhile, using:

```
def self.distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
  Math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
end
```

...and going from there.

**-- CURRENT STATUS --**

I'm currently trying to add all links coordinates to a hash as values and the link object itself as a key, to then work through each link's XY values and work out the distance, and create a new hash with the link object again as Key, and distance to that object as value. I have made the first hash, however unsure how to cycle through the values as individual XY's. (One link objects can have many XY points)

```
points_hash = Hash[ array.map {|k| [k, k.bends]} ]
```

**-- DESIRED OUTPUT --**

From:

```
{#<Link:0x803a2e8>=>[394514.80, 421898.01, 394512.92, 421895.82]...} #(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
```

to

```
{#<Link:0x803a2e8>=>[157],    #(distance in metres (value not real distance))
\#<Link:0x803a2e8>=>[196]...}  #(distance in metres (value not real distance))
```

Can give more information if its a little tricky to get what I'm after. Also happy to be told I'm going about this all wrong!

Many thanks.

Comment: 1. Given a link `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]` and a point `p = [x3,y3]` how is the distance from the link to `p`defined? Is it, for example, the distance from `p` to the point on the link that is closest to `p`? 2. Please give a small example (say two links) and show which link is closest and why. 3) There's no need to take square roots. Just find the link whose distance squared is minimum.

Comment: Hi Cary, yes that assumption is correct. The distance would be calculated for all points of the link `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]] ` to point `p = [x3,y3]`. In this example there would be 2 straight lines. If either of the distances are less than the specified distance in `manual_search_from_point(x, y, distance_from_point_to_search, collection_of_objects)` then I would like to return the link object as it satisfies the criteria of being within "distance_from_point_to_search" metres. If say, there was several links within that distance - I am hoping to return an array of these link objects.

Comment: Here's an example you may wish to include in your question. The links are `[[2,3],[5,7]]` and `[[7,6], 6,9]]`, the point is `[5,2]` and the maximum distance is `3.2`. I believe the first link meets the distance requirement, but the second does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach**

Consider the link

```
[a, b]
```

where `a` and `b` are two-element arrays that correspond to `x-y` coordinates in Euclidean space. I will assume `a != b`.

In vector terminology, every point on the line that goes through the points `a` and `b` can be expressed as:

```
αa + (1-α)b
```

for some value of the scalar `α`. `α` satisfies `0 <= α <= 1` for points falling on the *line segment* between `a` and `b`. Those points are said to comprise a *convex combination* of `a` and `b`. I will compute the value of `α` (`alpha`) that corresponds to a point that is on both the line that passes through `a` and `b` and line that is perpendicular to that line and passes through a given point `p`.

First calculate the slope of the line that passes between `a` and `b`. Let

```
a = [ax,ay]
b = [bx,by]
```

Points `c = [cx,cy]` on the line that passes through `a` and `b` are expressed:

```
cx = alpha*ax + (1-alpha)*bx
cy = alpha*ay + (1-alpha)*by
```

which we can simplify to:

```
cx = alpha*(ax-bx) + bx
cy = alpha*(ay-by) + by
```

Note that `cx` and `cy` equal `bx` and `by` when `alpha` is zero and equal `ax` and `ay` when `alpha` equals `1`.

Suppose now we are given a point:

```
p = [px,py]
```

and wish to find the point on the line (not necessarily the line segment) that passes through `a` and `b` that is the closest point to `p`. We can do that as follows.

First calculate the slope of the line that passes through `a` and `b` (assuming `bx != ax`, which would correspond to a vertical line):

```
slope = (by-ay)/(bx-ax)
```

Lines perpendicular to this line have a slope equal to:

```
pslope = -1/slope
```

Let's compute the intercept of such a line that passes through point `p`:

```
intercept + pslope*px = py
```

So

```
intercept = py - pslope*px
```

Now let's see where this line intersects the line that passes through `a` and `b` in terms of the value of `alpha`:

```
intercept + pslope(alpha*(ax-bx) + bx) = alpha*(ay-by) + by
```

Solving for alpha:

```
alpha = (by - pslope*bx - intercept)/(pslope*(ax-bx) - (ay-by))
```

Let's try this with an example. Consider just two links of a graph, as shown in the professionally-prepared drawing below. (Whoops! I see my graphic service neglected to label the point `[2,3]` as "A".) First consider the link, or line segment, `A-B` and the point `P`.

[image]

```
ax = 2
ay = 3

bx = 5
by = 7

px = 5
py = 2
```

```
slope = (by-ay).fdiv(bx-ax)
  #=> (7-3).fdiv(5-2) => 1.333.. 
pslope = -1.0/slope
  #=> -0.75 
intercept = py - pslope*px
  #=> 5.75 
alpha = (by - pslope*bx - intercept)/(pslope*(ax-bx) - (ay-by))
  #=> 0.8 
cx = alpha*(ax-bx) + bx
  #=> 2.6 
cy = alpha*(ay-by) + by
  #=> 3.8
```

Because `0 <= alpha (0.8) <= 1`, `(cx,cy)` falls in the line segment `A-B`, so that point is the closest point on the line segment to `P`, not just the point on the line going through `A` and `B` that is closest to `P`.

The square of the distance from `P` to `C` is found to equal

```
(cx-px)**2 + (cy-py)**2
  #=> (2.6-5.0)**2 + (3.8-2.0)**2 => 9
```

If we wished to include all links no farther than, say, `3.5` from `P`, that is equivalent to including all links whose squared distance to `P` is no more than:

```
max_dist_sqrd = 3.5**2
  #=> 12.25
```

As `9.0 <= max_dist_sqrd` (`12.25`), this link would be included.

Now consider the link `D-E`.

```
dx = 7
dy = 6

ex = 6
ey = 9

px = 5
py = 2
```

```
slope = (ey-dy).fdiv(ex-dx)
  #=> (9-6).fdiv(6-7) => -3.0 
pslope = -1.0/slope
  #=> 1.0/3.0 => 0.333
intercept = py - pslope*px
  #=> 2 - (0.333)*5 => 0.333..
alpha = (ey - pslope*ex - intercept)/(pslope*(dx-ex) - (dy-ey))
  #=> (9 - 0.333*6 - 0.333)/(0.333*(7-6) - (6-9)) #=> 2.0
```

Because `alpha > 1.0` we know that the point `F` is not on the line segment `D-E`. Let's take a brief excursion to see where the point is:

```
fx = alpha*(dx-ex) + ex
  #=> 2.0(7-6) + 6 => 8.0
fy = alpha*(dy-ey) + ey
  #=> 2.0(6-9) + 9 => 3.0
```

Because `alpha > 1.0` we know that the closest point to `P` on the line segment `D-E` is `D`. Had `alpha > 1.0`, the closest point would have been `E`.

We therefore find that the closest distance squared from the point `P` to the line segment `D-E` equals:

```
(dx-px)**2 + (dy-py)**2
  #=> (7-5)**2 + (6-2)**2 => 20
```

Since `20.0 > max_dist_sqrd` (`12.25`), this link would not be included.

**Code**

```
def links_in_point_circle(links, point, max_dist)
  max_dist_sqrd = max_dist**2
  links.select { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link, point) <= max_dist_sqrd }
end
```

```
def sqrd_dist_to_link( ((xlow,ylow),(xhigh,yhigh)),(px,py) )
  return vert_link_dist(xlow,ylow,yhigh,px,py) if xlow == xhigh
  slope = -1.0/((yhigh-ylow).fdiv(xhigh-xlow))
  intercept = py - slope*px
  alpha = (yhigh - slope*xhigh - intercept)/(slope*(xlow-xhigh) - (ylow-yhigh))
  closest_x, closest_y =
    case alpha
    when -Float::INFINITY...0
      [xhigh, yhigh]
    when 0..1.0 
      [alpha*(xlow-xhigh) + xhigh, alpha*(ylow-yhigh) + yhigh]
    else
      [xlow, ylow]
    end
  (closest_x-px)**2 + (closest_y-py)**2  
end
```

```
def vert_link_dist(xlow, ylow, yhigh, px, py)
  return Float::INFINITY if px != xlow 
  case
  when py < ylow   then (ylow-py)**2
  when ylow..yhigh then 0
  else                  (py-yhigh)**2
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
links    = [[[2,3],[5,7]], [[7,6], [6,9]]]
point    = [5,2]
max_dist = 3.5
```

```
links_in_point_circle(links, point, max_dist)
  #=> [[[2, 3], [5, 7]]]
```

Comment: Hi @Cary Swoveland, thanks very much for giving such an in-depth answer! Apologies for the delay, work and non-work time was focused elsewhere!. I have now gone through your response and gave it a whirl. As per your example it returns `[[[2, 3], [5, 7]]]` as it is the ONLY link within the specified distance. If I add `[[4,3],[9,7]]` into the links array (keeping `max_dist = 3.5`, this link will also be returned. I'm wondering if it is best to return only the closest link given a larger `max_dist`, or, using this current method and continually increasing the `max_dist` until 1 link is found.

Comment: If you want only the link closest to the point you could write `links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link, point) }`.

Comment: Thank you again, this has helped me achieve what I was after in the big picture. Overall what I was doing was trying to find the closest link (5000 in total) to every point (5000 in total) and updating an attribute of the point to give the ID of the link object. However the link and point had to exist within the same polygon (15 total). So the workflow is 1) for each point, assess polygon. 2) for each pipe, check if in same polygon to assign `valid`. 3) links can be made of many segments, get all coords of segments of "valid" links. 4) Use `links_in_point_circle(links, point, max_dist)`.

Comment: 5) Use `@closest_segment = links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link, point)}`. 6) Check all links to find which one contained that segment. (To get link object itself) 7) Update attributes of point using the link object. All in all I would like things to run faster, as I've undoubtedly done unnecessary work and looped within loops - but I'll see what I can improve myself and maybe create a new question for improvements in future. Just wanted to give you the bigger picture of how the code you provided would be applied. Thanks again!

Comment: rpg, I'm curious what your problem is that you have abstracted to polygons, links and points.

Comment: The data I'm using is all taken from GIS (Geographical Information Systems), and the software I'm using is a representation of that data. For example, a household (point) should be assigned to a nearby link (line with multiple segments), and there are a large number of both, sectioned into areas represented by polygons. The household should only be assigned to a link if they both are within the same polygon as each other.

Comment: It seems like a first step might be to create hash `h` such that `h[p] ={ points: points, links: links }`, where `points` and `links` are arrays of points and links that are within polygon `p`. If each link can span multiple polygons, perhaps break it into multiple links, each falling entirely within one polygon.

Comment: Thankfully the way the links are split there should be no links going over polygons. The software I'm using has an in-built ruby library with private methods that can be used, one of which allows for assessing if things are within a polygon. So my initial 'links' in the query is an array of links which have already been assessed as "valid" as such. The tricky part for me now is finding a way using your code to return the `|link|` object itself rather than just the products of link's attributes (the XY coordinates themselves)!

Comment: Consider `links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link_coordinates(link), point)}`, where `links` is a collection of `link` objects.

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks again for your input! I have given the above a go and I feel things are almost there. Due to formatting restriction, I have provided an "answer" below to highlight  where I'm falling down - I will update that post once I have it resolved!

Comment: Actually I think adding a "flatten(1)" to 

```def link_coordinates(link)
  link = link.bends.each_slice(2).each_cons(2).to_a 
end``` may have helped - I shall have a check.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an [AABB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume)-Tree: AABB-Tree is an spatial index i.e., it accelerate spatial queries. You can use other index datastructure like kd-tree, uniform grid, quad-tree, R-tree, etc. But I found AABB-tree simpler and near optimal for range queries (what you want to do is a range query e.g., like [nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search))

   1.1) First put each and every link into an AABB. Compute the centroid of each AABB.

   1.2) Put all your AABBs into a big AABB that contains all of them. Make that big AABB the tree **root** node.

   1.3) Find the largest side of the big AABB (it can be X or Y).

   1.4) Sort all the AABBs by centroid coordinate (X or Y) corresponding to the largest side.

   1.5) Find the middle of the sorted list and split it in two lists.

   1.6) Create two child nodes attached to the root node and assign one list to each node.

   1.7) Call step 1.2) recursively to build each child node into a subtree.

   1.8) Stop the recursion when the list is of size <= N. Then assign all AABBs to that node.
2. Do a range query to find the closest link to a point (i.e., traverse the tree recursively).

   2.1) Define a circle of infinite radius centered at the point you want to query. Pass the circle as parameter to the traverse function.

   2.2) If the root node's AABB intersect with the circle, then call recursively the traverse function with the left and the right children. The order is important, so you should choose first the child closer to the circle center.

   2.3) If the node is a leaf node (i.e., no children, it hold the list of AABBs of links) then check if circle intersect the AABBs of the links, if it does then compute the distance of point to each link and keep the shortest distance. While you compute the distance to each link compare it with the radius of the circle. If the distance is smaller than the radius **update the radius if the circle to the shortest distance**, and keep the ID of the link with shortest distance.
3. Once traverse function finish, you will get the shortest distance in logarithmic time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and the reading material! I had attempted something similar to what Cary had offered in the past which is why I opted for that methodology, but I'll be sure to investigate this further in future too.

Answer (score 1):

Using methods provided by Cary Swoveland above, the answer is almost there. Using an example below:

```
class Link
  attr_accessor :bends
  def initialize(bends)
    @bends = bends
  end
end

link_1 = Link.new([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
link_2 = Link.new([5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8])
link_3 = Link.new([11, 11, 14, 14, 17, 17, 22, 22, 25, 25])

valid_links = Array.new
links = [link_1, link_2, link_3]
links.each do |link|
  # Conditional goes here, to populate valid_links
  valid_links << link
end

point = [1.1, 1.1]

def link_coordinates(link)
  # To get the link XYs in desired format:
  # [[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], [[x2, y2], [x3, y3]], [[x3, y3], [x4, y4]]]  (1)
  link = link.bends.each_slice(2).each_cons(2).to_a 
  #=> [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [3, 3]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]]]  (for first link)
end

closest_segment = valid_links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link_coordinates(link), point)}
```

The above yields an error within `sqrd_dist_to_link`. Where before when "links" was only using values and in the format:

```
links = [[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], [[x2, y2], [x3, y3]], [[x3, y3], [x4, y4]]]  (2)
```

```
@closest_segment = links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link, point)}
```

succeeded in returning the nearest XY coordinates of the segment in the format: [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]].

Considering the "links" labelled "(1)" and the links labelled "(2)" output the same format, I'm uncertain how to tweak things so that `valid_links.min_by { |link| sqrd_dist_to_link(link_coordinates(link), point)}` will retrieve the link object of the nearest XY segment as desired.

**Note:**

I will update this when I have it working correctly so that it qualifies correctly as an answer.

Comment: Think of each instance of `Link` as a snake comprised of links. If you want to find which valid snake is closest to a given point, you need to define a metric. If that is the squared distance from the point to the closest link in the valid snake, perhaps you need something like `valid_snakes.min_by { |valid_snake| valid_snake.map { |link_in_valid_snake|   sqrd_dist_to_link(link_in_valid_snake, point)}.min }`. Also, if `@bends` is meant to be something like `[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]` it may be clearer to write `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]]`.

Comment: Looks like its working now using that idea! ```@closest_segment = links.min_by { |x| x.bends.each_slice(2).each_cons(2).to_a.map { |coords| sqrd_dist_to_link(coords, point)}.min }```. I'll test it out a little more but at the moment that saves me from carrying out steps 6 and 7 I mentioned in another comment, cutting out 33% of the run time. Now likely going to try re-incorporating the max search radius for either the accepted "valid" links or the point to link segment search. Thanks again.